# Find how many positive numbers there are in my array

Tags: c, arrays

How to find how many positive numbers there are in my code? I am getting the wrong output, please explain in detail where my mistake here is. I wish to have the exact output as desired. If I entered `6` as `n` then I will insert six numbers and the output will show me how many positive numbers I have inserted.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    int i;
    int p = 0;
    int arr_i;
    for (arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++) {
        scanf("%d",&arr[arr_i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int arr_index=i;
        if (arr[arr_index] > 0) {
            p++;
        }
        printf("%d",p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "wrong output". Edit your question to show the actual input, the actual output, and the expected output for that input.

Comment: There's no need to have `arr_index` - you can use `i` to access elements of `arr` like `arr[i]`

Comment: @ChrisTurner even better, rename as 'enteredNum' and use it in the for().  Dump the single-letter var 'i' completely.

Comment: is 0 positive? can you give input and output exanoke and explain what went wrong?

Comment: Note that the only header you need in this code is `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: You should print `p` after the loop, not inside, and add a newline at the end of the format string too

Comment: You don't even need an array for this problem. You can easily check while inputting numbers whether they're less than zero or not, and count accordingly the "not" case. You don't need to retain the numbers for anything if all you care about is how many were non-negative. Just count them as they come in, and print the final result when finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Just Print `p` outside the `for` loop.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    int i;
    int p = 0;
    int arr_i;
    for (arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[arr_i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        int arr_index=i;
        if (arr[arr_index] > 0) 
        {
            p++;
        }
    }
            printf("%d",p);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need t allocate dynamic memory  using malloc - hope this helps

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
char c;
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int * arr;
int i;
int p = 0;
arr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] > 0)
        {
            p++;
}
}


printf(" %d", p);

return 0;
```

}